# 紹介してもいいんですけれどもね｡

Tags: translation

Can someone help me with that, I'm not sure about the translation.

"**紹介してもいいんですけれどもね｡**"

I translate this like this but I not sure about it :

"**It also would be great to make the presentation**"

or maybe it's just

"It's not necessary to make presentation"

I'm not sure about **もいいんです**

Comment: I don't care about introducing that.

Comment: Why it's not translate 'Can I make the presentation" ? Is it because けれども ??  [link](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13152/what-is-the-literal-meaning-of-%E3%83%9E%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9F%E3%81%AB%E3%83%90%E3%83%A9%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6)

Comment: How about "Although I may make the presentation."

Comment: Oh I think I understand, Like "I can but I don't really want" is that it ?

Comment: I may make the presentation but...

Comment: Yes, that sentence is very correct.

Comment: The guy does clearly not want to do the presentation man. read between the lines.

Answer (score 6):

～してもいい is commonly used to give or request permission, e.g. 「入っ**てもいい**ですよ。」"You may come in." (giving permission) / 「電話を借り**てもいい**ですか？」"May I use your phone?" (requesting permission). **But** in your example:

> 紹介**してもいい**んですけれどもね｡

the してもいい means "I am willing to do~~" "I am ready to do~~", rather than "I may~~ / I am allowed to~~".

> "**I am willing to** introduce (someone/something)(to someone), but..."

The ～けれどもね at the end, literally "Although..." or "... but", adds a nuance of uncertainty, hesitation or maybe reluctance, like "...but only if~~" or "...but I'm not sure~~", depending on the context.

Answer (score 0):

- I can introduce you, but ...
- I am OK to introduce you, but ...
- I would be OK to introduce you.