# キミの心が、綺麗なのがいけないんだよ? >> What does this mean ? "Why is your heart ,it's beauty made me so hopeless/defenseless against you ?"

Tags: meaning, expressions, japanese-to-english, conversations, video-games

Context is a girl talking with MC ,looks like they're about to H

> Girl: キミとひとつになるってことに……私、期待してる。
>
> 身体の奥、熱くなって……胸の鼓動が早くなって
>
> なんだろう、この気持ちは……もしかして、一目惚れってやつなのかな。
>
> 私にはそんなこと、絶対にないと思ってたのに
>
> **キミの心が、綺麗なのがいけないんだよ?**

I don't understand this sentence, my guess is "Why is your heart, it's beauty made me so hopeless/defenseless against you ?"

Hope someone will help me understand this sentence

Comment: Is that question mark part of the original sentence?

Comment: @aguijonazo There was another question on the use of よ？　which I can’t find right now.

Comment: Found it: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6524/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While いけない can indeed mean “hopeless”, in this context it is used more in the meaning of “not good; wrong”.

Some examples from Kenkyusha J-E dictionary:

> なんていけない子だろう.
> What a naughty child you are!
>
> いけない, いけないと思いながら, つい彼の言いなりになってしまった.
> Against my better judgment, I went along with him.
>
> 君がいけないんだ.
> It’s your fault. | You are to blame.

Especially the last example fits your context well.

Additionally, 綺麗 means not only “beautiful/pretty” but also “clean/pure (i.e. free of dirt/impurities)”, both in literal and figurative sense.

So the phrase could mean something like:

> It’s all because your heart/soul is so pure